# Need To Automate Sandbox Refresh Activity

Tags: sandbox-refresh

We have received a requirement where we need to automate the sandbox refresh activity. Is there any way to automate the same?

Thanks,
Ravi Ranjan

Comment: Have you considered Scratch orgs ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm) object to create, refresh, and delete sandboxes. In essence, you use the Tooling API to create, refresh, and delete sandboxes by performing the corresponding action on the associated SandboxInfo object. Create a new record to create a new sandbox, change the appropriate fields to refresh a sandbox, and delete the SandboxInfo record to delete the record. Please read the documentation for additional details.